# How can I wrap an array element in a html tag after being sorted?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to wrap each array element in a span. So I could later add a class. But really can't figure out how.
Here's my code:

```
let hit = 0;
let pick = props.selected.length;
let payout = null;
let currentPayout;
let pickList = '';
props.selected.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}).forEach((n) => {
    if (pickList.length) {
        pickList += ' ';
    }
  // Here's the mess, I'd like to be able to wrap each number in a span.
       pickList =+ n;
});
```

Comment: You want to create an HTML string, or a DOM node list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate HTML, you could do this:

```
let pickList = props.selected.sort((a, b) => a - b)
                    .map(n => `<span>${n}</span>`)
                    .join('');
```

Be aware that `sort` will mutate the `selected` property in-place. Also, the compare function that you pass to `sort` is allowed to return other numbers besides -1, 0, and 1 (only the sign is important and 0), so it is quite practical to just return `a - b`.

If your question was to create an array of span node objects, then do this:

```
let pickList = props.selected.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .map(n => {
        const span = document.createElement('<span>');
        span.textContent = n;
        return span;
    });
```

Now *pickList* is an array of DOM nodes. If you need to display them on the page (document), then use the `appendChild` method on the container element for each of the nodes in the array.